# how can I create an hook when external id change

Tags: wordpress, hooks, external-id

I would to ask you , on how can create an event (programatically) when I change the external ID in contact form, how can I t make some kind of process like validation in another module or service I know I can create something like a hook but I dont know how to start working with hooks in civiccrm, is there any document, book ,link, video, note where I 
can learn about it? I would really appreciate this, thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Aneury, are you comfortable with hooks (actions & filters) in WordPress? If so, I can help you do this in a WordPress plugin.

Comment: I'm not comfortable with hooks yet, but it could be! let me know how to proceed with this, please.

Answer (score 1):

**Create an extension**

The first step to create a hook is to create an extension.
I'd recommend installing [civix](https://github.com/totten/civix) which can generate an empty extension by simply typing the command :

```
civix generate:module myextension
```

Go check https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/ for more details about extensions.

All you need to know for now is that civix will create a file called myextension.php where you can put your hooks. There are a few hooks commented as examples in the generated files.

**Create the hook**

A hook is simply a function that start with the name of your extension and finish with the name of the hook. For example `hook_civicrm_post` will be named `myextension_civicrm_post` in the extension we've just created.

In your case, I believe `hook_civicrm_post` is the one you want to use but you can see the documentation about the hooks in :

- https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/
- https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/list/

Comment: If they want to validate the external id then hook_civicrm_validateForm might be a better fit than _post.

Comment: Yes, depends on what the OP wants. If it's a kind of sync that is needed and that needs to work with API calls, then _post is probably the way to go. If it's for UI validation, then validateForm might be better.

Comment: I'm reading about it, is interesting but how or where should I add my function callback with the singleton  `Civi::dispatcher()>addListener`? for me is not clear this part yet, it could be directly in my extesion? it would be loaded when somebody request something related to my custom extension?

Comment: You probably don't need a dispatcher as the standard hooks will be automatically called if properly named in your (activated) extension. 
In some specific case, you might need to use the addListener like so :

Civi::service('dispatcher')->addListener('hook_civicrm_pageRun', 'reorderdashboard_symfony_civicrm_pageRun', -255);

See also : https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.shoreditch/pull/316/files

Comment: Can hooks only be used by extensions? Is there a way to use hooks from within my theme's functions.php file for example?